# Can I have the sum() in one select?

Tags: sql

I have e table like this :

```
A B
1 1.5
1 1.5
2 2.3
2 2.3
2 2.3
3 1.5
3 1.5
```

how could i make the sum of column B, grouped by in 1.5, 2.3 and 1.5.
in few words, I want to group by first and then make the sum(), but in one select.

in this table, if you group by A column the result is:

```
A B
1 1.5
2 2.3
3 1.5
```

now i want to sum() the B column.

Comment: Could you add the expected output, please?

Comment: I don't think I'm reading this correctly.  Can you add an example output from the query you need?

Comment: Yeah what do you want? `1: 3; 2: 6.9; 3: 3`or `1.5: 6, 2.3: 6.9`?

Comment: I believe he wants a total of 5.3 (1.5+2.3+1.5).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive, but it looks like you want the sum for each individual value in column B (with column A being ignored completely)

Give this a try:

```
select b, sum(b)
from tableName
group by b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select A, sum(B) from table
group by A
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This would sum distinct rows after grouping on a and b:

```
select sum(b)
from (
    select b
    from YourTable
    group by a, b
) sub
```

This would sum all distinct values of B:

```
select sum(distinct b)
from YourTable
```

This would sum the highest values of B for each value of A:

```
select sum(maxb)
from (
    select max(b) as maxb
    from YourTable
    group by a
) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, this will do it for you:

```
select a, sum(b)
from myTable
group by a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(B)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM tbl) PLEASE
```